# Вывод и последующая сортировка записей

Tags: php, mysql, sql, сортировка

Есть 4 таблицы:
**fandom** - Название группы диалогов.
**dialog** - Список диалогов в группе.
**dialog_users** - Пользователи в каждом диалоге группы.
**chat** - Сообщения в определенном диалоге.

---

**Задача:**
 Вывести на страницу профиля диалоги в порядке (Новые выше) + выше новых диалогов выводить те диалоги, в которых добавлены новые сообщения (Пример как ВК, Facebook).
Готовые наработки: Есть вывод диалогов. Нет сортировки по сообщениям.

---

**Код наработок:**

```
$sql_dialog = mysql_query("
SELECT `d`.*,
(SELECT `f_title` FROM `fandom` WHERE `id` = `d`.fandom) AS `f_title` 
FROM `dialog_users` d 
WHERE `d`.users = '$_SESSION[id]' 
GROUP BY `d`.fandom ORDER BY `date` DESC");

    while($dialog = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_dialog)){
        $array_dialog[] = $dialog['dialog'];
    }

//Вывод сообщений по диалогам
$sql_chat = mysql_query("
SELECT `dialog`,`text`,`status` 
FROM `chat` 
WHERE `dialog` IN (".implode(',',$array_dialog).") 
GROUP BY `dialog` ORDER BY `date` DESC");

    while($chat = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_chat)){
        $array_chat[] = $chat['dialog'];
    }

    foreach(){
    //Соединение обеих массивов
    }
```

Идеально было бы сделать все это в одном запросе.
По данному коду мне не понятно, как сделать вывод диалогов по новым сообщениям (За это отвечает поле **status(1/0)** в таблице **chat**) и добавление условия, если **status = 0** то сортировать только по **date**.
 
Если есть мысли как возможно доделать этот код, был бы безмерно благодарен Вашей помощи...

Comment: А сами сообщения надо выдавать ? И как определяется, что сообщение новое ? А так то одним запросом можно сделать вообще все что угодно ...

Comment: @Mike status (0/1). Да, текст. Но и еще исходя из status, думаю добавить изменение стиля диалога. Да знаю что можно так сделать, пробовал скомбинировать, но еще не делал такие выводы, из-за этого решил в 2 цикла. Но в любом случае, есть куда расти.

Comment: Я так понял вам нужен на выходе практически первый запрос из примера кода, но что бы он сортировал еще и по наличию сообщений с status=1 ?

Comment: @Mike Получается да, но и по date, ведь если нет нового сообщения по status, все ровно нужно сортировать исходя из старых сообщений. То есть нужно некое условие, если status = 0 то сортировать только по дате. Сейчас обновлю пост.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `d`.*,
       (SELECT `f_title` FROM `fandom` WHERE `id` = `d`.fandom) AS `f_title`,
       exists(select 1 from `chat` c where c.dialog=d.dialog and status=1) AS `newMsg`
  FROM `dialog_users` d 
 WHERE `d`.users = '$_SESSION[id]' 
 GROUP BY `d`.fandom
 ORDER BY newMsg DESC, `date` DESC
```

Вместо exists (которое проверяет только наличие таких записей) можно выбирать например количество сообщений в chat или дату последнего нового сообщения.

Или например текст последнего сообщения:

```
SELECT `d`.*,
       (SELECT `f_title` FROM `fandom` WHERE `id` = `d`.fandom) AS `f_title`,
       (select text from `chat` c
         where c.dialog=d.dialog and status=1
         order by c.date desc
         limit 1
       ) AS `lastMsg`
  FROM `dialog_users` d 
 WHERE `d`.users = '$_SESSION[id]' 
 GROUP BY `d`.fandom
 ORDER BY lastMsg DESC, `date` DESC
```

Comment: А если текст сообщения, пишу вместо 1  text, выводит все ровно значение status.

Comment: @АльбертУшаков Ну так там же exists он возвращает только 0 если записей нет и 1 если есть, что внутри запрос возвращает его не интересует.  сделайте без exists подзапрос, только явно ограничте limit 1 что бы одну запись возвращал

Comment: А можете показать как? Уж наверняка чтобы было ясно...и закрою вопрос.

Comment: @АльбертУшаков А текст из какого сообщения именно со статусом 1 и какого по дате первого или последнего

Comment: Ну хотя я вроде бы убрал exists , добавил лимит с ORDER BY `date` DESC и выводит нормально. Ладно, думаю правильно, спасибо.

Comment: А слушайте, забыл спросить, а как вывести 2 значение, то есть текст и статус?)

Comment: @АльбертУшаков Я же специально спрашивал, достаточно ли сортировки. Если 2 поля - то либо второй подзапрос, что криво, либо в корне все менять. И зачем вам там статус если этот подзапрос (ради правильной сортировки) берет только записи со статусом 1, и если текст есть - значит статус 1, а если нет - то 0