# Чат с несколькими пользователями (Упрощение sql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Прошлый вопрос связанный с этим [Вывод и последующая сортировка записей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/576920/212684)

---

**Задача:**
Максимально скомбинировать sql в один или два запроса. Пробовал по разному, но не могу понять как лучше это сделать.

---

**Рабочий вариант кода:**

```
//Вывод группу диалога
$sql_fandom = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`f_title` 
FROM `fandom` WHERE `id` = '".intval($im)."'
LIMIT 1");
$fandom = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_fandom);

    //Проверка на существования группы
    if(isset($fandom['id'])){

        //Вывод пользователя по сессии и определение id диалога в группе
        $sql_dialog_users = mysql_query("SELECT `dialog` 
        FROM `dialog_users` 
        WHERE `users` = '$_SESSION[id]' AND `fandom` = '$fandom[id]'
        LIMIT 1");
        $dialog_users = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_dialog_users);

        //Вывод всех пользователей в этом диалоге в массив
        $sql_users = mysql_query("SELECT `users` 
        FROM `dialog_users` 
        WHERE `fandom` = '$fandom[id]' AND `dialog` = '$dialog_users[dialog]'");

        while($users = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_users)){
            $users_array[] = $users['users'];
        }

        //Вывод всех данных пользователей
        $sql_users_profil = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`name`,`avatar` 
        FROM `users` 
        WHERE `id` IN (".implode(',',$users_array).")");

        while($users_profil = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_users_profil)){
            $users_profil_array[$users_profil['id']] = $users_profil;
        }

        //Вывод сообщений по id диалога
        $sql_chat = mysql_query("SELECT * 
        FROM (SELECT * FROM `chat` 
        WHERE `dialog` = '$dialog_users[dialog]' 
        ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 50) A 
        ORDER BY `date`");

print<<<HERE
<div class="chat-vivod" id="messages">
HERE;

if(mysql_num_rows($sql_chat) == 0){
$echo = '<center>Диалог отсутствует</center><br>';
}

while($chat = mysql_fetch_array($sql_chat)){
    $chat_users = array(
    'name'   =>           $users_profil_array[$chat['users']]['name'],
    'avatar' => avatar    ($users_profil_array[$chat['users']]['avatar']),
    'text'   => to_link   ($chat['text']),
    'date'   => date_smart($chat['date'])
    );

print<<<HERE
<label class='chat-box' id='chat-box-$chat[id]'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox chat-box-checkbox' id='chat-box-checkbox-$chat[id]' onChange='checked_chat($chat[id]);' name='chat_text' />
    <div class='chat-box-avatar image-min' style='background-image: url($chat_users[avatar]);'></div>
    <div class='chat-box-content'>
        <div>$chat_users[name]<small>$chat_users[date]</small></div>
        <div>$chat_users[text]</div>
    </div>
</label>
</div>
HERE;
}
```

Comment: Вот в этом запросе `SELECT `dialog` 
        FROM `dialog_users` 
        WHERE `users` = '$_SESSION[id]' AND `fandom` = '$fandom[id]' LIMIT 1` какая 1 запись выбирается, тут не задана сортировка - следовательно БД отдает первую попавшуюся подходящую запись. В БД всегда одна по заданным условиям отбора, или их может быть несколько и вы действительно хотите получить первую попавшуюся ?

Comment: @Mike Этот запрос для получения id диалога, так как в группе может быть несколько диалогов и нужно вывести тот, на который подписан участник. То есть вывод должен быть одного id по заданным критериям.

Comment: а в БД может быть по заданным критериям более одной записи (для чего тут limit 1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так и не понял зачем список пользователей получался из dialog_users, посчитал что нужных пользователей можно легко найти сразу в users по id. Предлагаю первый запрос оставить как есть, что бы быстро убедится, что группа существует и получить f_title (который вы правда после не используете). А все остальное должно получиться как то так:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
     SELECT c.*,
            u.name as user_name, u.avatar
       FROM `chat` c, `users` u
      WHERE u.id=c.users
        AND c.dialog IN(SELECT `dialog` FROM dialog_users
                         WHERE `users` = '$_SESSION[id]' AND `fandom` = intval($im)
                         LIMIT 1
                       )
      ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 50
  ) A 
 ORDER BY `date`
```

Comment: dialog_users - это подписка пользователей. Опишу структуру и систему. Пользователь на странице видит группы, жмет подписку и скрипт сам определяет его в тот диалог, в котором меньше народу. При переходе на страницу с чатом, id остается группы но исходя из подписки пользователя, выводиться диалог. Вывод группы в основном тут не нужно, я ее добавил чтобы просто вывести f_title, чтобы пользователь видел в какой группе находиться.

Comment: @АльбертУшаков Вы запрос посмотрите, я на 90% уверен, что он выдает сейчас те же данные которые ваш старый скрипт. Таблица dialog_users в этом запросе может понадобится только если в таблице chat с данным dialog могут быть сообщения пользователей которых почему то нет в таблице dialog_users с таким же dialog и вот такие сообщения вы выдавать не хотите

Comment: А да, Вы правы. Только в место IN наверное =, так как одна цифра на выводе. Работает. Спасибо.

Comment: @АльбертУшаков Я боюсь писать = потому что если подзапрос не вернет ни одной строки, то во многих БД это приведет к ошибке выполнения, в отличие от IN. Как в MySQL не знаю, может ему и все равно

Comment: с IN не работает. Ну а в общем то если на выводе будет пустота, поставлю обработчик. Но это почти что невозможно в данной системе, так как все диалоги проверяются в админке.